# C# textbox load

Tags: c#, textbox, load

How do I automatically load content of a txt file to my textbox . To further explain when I start up my program I want the textbox to show the last saved entry from the txt file .

Comment: When the TextBox is loaded, read the text file, and set the TextBox to what you read back. Also, before finishing, make sure the text file is updated with the latest TextBos info.

Comment: If you want do load the text file go ahead and load it. If you have a specific problem, please mention that in your question.

Comment: Well i tried the readalltext command but it didn't work , also if someone provided a code for this i would be very grateful :3

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [LoadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.loadfile%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method, it sounds like it does just what you need.

e.g.
`MyTextBox.LoadFile("MyFile.txt");`